# Django Web Application, Facebook login

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, django-allauth, django-socialauth

I am building a basic social media web application and I would like my only login point to be via facebook login. After doing a fare amount of research, I have seen multiple third party authorization frameworks that plug in with facebook, but I was wondering if there were any opinions on what the best foot forward would be.

Additionally, how would I go about still being able to use sessions/cookies within Django if I use fb login?

All answers are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SocialAuth (https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django), this app allows you to let users log in via many common SocialMedia-accounts, e.g. facebook. Upon login, the app will create a user in your database, which you can then use as if the user logged in with a local account. Therefore, the session will still be handled by django, fb only sends you some information about the user (e.g. first- and lastname, email, etc. [configurable in your settings.py])

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Would django-allauth provide the same functionality. If so, which is more preferred?